# Pivot Creates an extra Row for Null values of Pivot Key

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

I am using oracle sql developer and trying to pivot in based on IssueId and expecting to get one row. But it creates an extra row for null values of issue but I want all values in one row. Please, see below scenario for better explanation of this confusing problem.

Table I have after joins :

Data:

[image]

Current Result with Extra Null Row:

[image]

Expected Result:

[image]

My Query:

```
select *
from
(
select  TableB.SEQ_ID,TableA.ISSUEID , TableC.Question
from TableC RIGHT JOIN  TableB  ON TableC.QUESTIONID = TableB.QUESTION_ID 
LEFT JOIN TableA ON TableB.QUESTION_ID = TableA.QUESTIONID AND ISSUEID = 3250

) d
pivot
(
  MAX(Question) 
  for SEQ_ID   in ( 1, 2, 3 ,4, 5 )
) piv;
```

Any suggestions related to this is appreciated. Thank You!

Comment: [Please post formatted text not images](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the intermediate result set is what you expect to see and the left/right outer joins are necessary for what you're trying to do, you could just replace the null issue IDs from rows not matching in table A, using an analytic aggregate:

```
max(TableA.ISSUEID) over () as ISSUEID
```

With sample data that gets the same intermediate result you showed, the modified inner query:

```
select  TableB.SEQ_ID, max(TableA.ISSUEID) over () as ISSUEID, TableC.Question
from TableC
RIGHT JOIN  TableB  ON TableC.QUESTIONID = TableB.QUESTION_ID 
LEFT JOIN TableA ON TableB.QUESTION_ID = TableA.QUESTIONID AND TableA.ISSUEID = 3250;
```

gets

```
    SEQ_ID    ISSUEID QUESTION     
---------- ---------- -------------
         1       3250 How are You? 
         2       3250 Hows it going
         3       3250 Is It Okay?  
         4       3250 Whats Up?    
         5       3250 Really?
```

and when pivoted:

```
select *
from
(
  select  TableB.SEQ_ID, max(TableA.ISSUEID) over () as ISSUEID, TableC.Question
  from TableC
  RIGHT JOIN  TableB  ON TableC.QUESTIONID = TableB.QUESTION_ID 
  LEFT JOIN TableA ON TableB.QUESTION_ID = TableA.QUESTIONID AND TableA.ISSUEID = 3250
) d
pivot
(
  MAX(Question)
  for SEQ_ID   in ( 1, 2, 3 ,4, 5 )
) piv;
```

gets

```
   ISSUEID 1             2             3             4             5            
---------- ------------- ------------- ------------- ------------- -------------
      3250 How are You?  Hows it going Is It Okay?   Whats Up?     Really?
```

---

You could get the same result with:

```
select * from (
  select b.seq_id, a.issueid, c.question
  from tableb b
  join tablec c on c.questionid = b.question_id 
  cross join (
    select issueid from tablea where issueid = 3250
  ) a
) d
pivot
(
  max(question)
  for seq_id in (1, 2, 3 ,4, 5)
);
```

(or `cross apply` in 12c+), which also works with condition `>= 3250`. This just lists all five questions against every matching issue ID. That may not actually be what you want to do, but it's what your very limited sample data and expected results suggest.

Comment: This will work only for one issueid! In my case there are hundreds of them.

Comment: Your query is filtering on a single one. We can't guess what you really want to do.

Comment: I did that to make the scenario clear. Actually the condition is TableA.ISSUEID > 3250 instead if TableA.ISSUEID = 3250. So there will be multiple rows after transpose based on different IssueIDs.

Comment: @Programmermid - but if they all end up with all the questions anyway, what's the point of the joins? You seem to want to just show one row for every issue ID which shows all five questions. If that isn't what you want then you should ask a new question with more representative data and expected results.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want valid issues, then don't mess around with all those outer joins.  Just start with the table that has the rows you want to keep, us `left join` for the other tables, and filter the first table in the `where` clause:

```
from (select TableB.SEQ_ID, TableA.ISSUEID , TableC.Question
      from TableA LEFT JOIN
           TableB
           on TableB.QUESTION_ID = TableA.QUESTIONID LEFT JOIN
           TableC 
           on TableC.QUESTIONID = TableB.QUESTION_ID 
      where  tableA.ISSUEID = 3250 
     ) d
```